# Extracting columns from sql table with php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

My query selects all columns from my table

```
$spool = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM `tablename`');
```

then I display the results in a table. I need to display all columns. This is the way I do it.

```
echo "<table>";
  if ( !empty( $spool ) ) {
      echo  "<tr><th> header </th></tr>";
             foreach ( $spool as $a ) {
                    echo "<tr><th>" . $a->columnname1 . "</th><th>" .$a->columnnameN . "</th></tr>";
                }   

    }
echo "</table>";
```

Now since I have around 40 columns, I'd like to ask if there is a more intelligent and less tedious way of displaying them.

Comment: share a screenshot or fiddle

Comment: for 40 columns and you want to show all,  usually x-axis scroll on table div . and condensed table, less padding in cells etc

Comment: My question is a php one. Instead of doing $a->columnname for each of them, is there a shorter way to write it and still display all of them.

Comment: I know that I can display them all if I wrote $a->columnname for every single column but that would be tedious.

Comment: What is `$a` an instance of?

Comment: oh , you mean $a->columnname1  , $a->columnname2 . . . $a->columnname40 , you want to avoid it . right?

Comment: Yes I want to avoid that.

Comment: from your query, its simple, but probably you have a different query and you are getting different result then we think, its more of your loop logic.
try nested loop, first loop             `foreach ( $spool as $key => $val  )`  and 2nd as            `foreach ( $val as $a )` and `echo $a`

Comment: You should fetch the rows as associative arrays rather than objects. Then you can do `foreach ($row as $columnname => $value)`.

Comment: Take a look at the second argument of `wpdb::get_results`, use `ARRAY_A` to get an associative array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably you need nested loops,  you are getting result probably  like this

```
array(
    0:{column1:test,column2:test . . . },
    1:{column1:test,column2:test . . . }
)
```

so you can try this way

```
    echo "<table>";
    if ( !empty( $spool ) ) {
      echo  "<tr><th> header </th></tr>";
        foreach ( $spool as $key => $value  ) {
           echo '<tr>';
             foreach ( $value as $a ) {
                      echo "<th>" . $a. "</th>";
                 }   
            echo '</tr>';
          }
      }
      echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have objects you could cast them to arrays and use implode.
(But attribute order could be different from what you want.)

```
<?php
class A
{   
    public $foo = 'bing'; 
    public $bar = 'bang';
    public $baz = 'bong';    
}
$spool = [new A, new A];

echo '<table>';
foreach($spool as $a) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . implode('</td><td>', (array) $a) . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Output:

```
<table><tr><td>bing</td><td>bang</td><td>bong</td></tr><tr><td>bing</td><td>bang</td><td>bong</td></tr></table>
```